# DIV overlaps and anything below that div keeps showing on the div

Tags: html, css

I am having a DIV which renders fine. Anything below this DIV keeps showing on the DIV (not below the DIV). Need help to resolve this issue. I tried solution provided in other answers related to this but it did resolve my issue. 
Issue 1: The TEXT Cham Cham Recipe Description should come after the table ends 
Issue 2: The grey div should be on the right in desktop view and below the table in mobile view.I am not able to include complete HTML and CSS due to character limit.

```css
html,body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #ffe2ad;
  height: 100%;
}

a {
  color: #000;
}

/* header */


/*mobile*/
@media (min-width: 48em) 
{ 

  .header li {
    float: left;
  }
  .header li a {
    padding: 15px 15px;
  }
  .header .menu {
    clear: none;
    float: right;
    max-height: none;
  }
  .header .menu-icon {
    display: none;
  }
}
/* 48em = 768px @ 16pt font */
/*menu ends here*/

/* Create three unequal columns that floats next to each other for equip*/
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* Create three unequal columns that floats next to each other */
.maincolumn {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
 
}

.mainleft, .mainright {
  width: 10%;
}

.mainmiddle {
  width: 80%;


}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.mainrow:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* disclosure, print and share buttons*/

.discloseshareprintcolumn {
  float: left;
}

.discloseshareprintleft, .discloseshareprintright {
  width: 50%;
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */
.discloseprintrow:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.discloseprintcolumn {
  float: left;
  height: 50px; /* Should be removed. Only for demonstration */
}

.discloseprintleft, .discloseprintright {
  width: 50%;
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */
.discloseprintrow:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* Responsive layout - makes the three columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
/* For mobile*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {

  .discloseshareprintcolumn {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .discloseshareprintleft, .discloseshareprintright {
  height: 7%;
}
  .maincolumn {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .mainleft, .mainright {
  height: 20%;
}
}
/* For tablet(IPAD) portrait & landscape*/
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  
  {
   .maincolumn {
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .discloseshareprintcolumn
  {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .mainleft, .mainright {
  height: 50%;
  width:100%;
}
/*.header li {
    float: left;
  }*/

}
```

```html
<h2>Three Unequal Columns</h2>

<div class="mainrow">
  <div class="maincolumn mainleft" style="background-color:#aaa;">
   <div class="RecipeTitle" style="text-align:left">
  <h2>Column 3</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="maincolumn mainmiddle" style="background-color:white;">
   <h1>Cham Cham Recipe|Indian Sweets Recipe|Dessert Recipe</h1>
     <div class="discloseshareprintrow">
     <div class="discloseshareprintcolumn discloseshareprintleft">
     
    

     <div class="discloseshareprintcolumn discloseshareprintright">
      <div class="discloseprintrow">
       <div class="discloseprintcolumn discloseprintleft">

        <!--<b>Disclosure:</b> Puchase made via affliate link(s) on this site will earn us commission.-->
        <!--<a href="#" title="Snacks"><span style="text-align: left; font-size:x-small;">Advertisement disclosure</span></a>-->
        </div>
        <div class="discloseprintcolumn discloseprintright">
        <?php include_once("NEWprinter.php");?>
        </div>
        <br>
     </div>
    
     </div>
   </div>
      </div><h2>Utensils/Items used for cooking</h2>  
<div class="toolequip" style="width: 30%; height: 130px; background-color:#ED5E13; float:left; text-align:center; border-bottom: 1px dotted;border-left: 1px dotted;border-color: #BFBFBF; padding-top:15px;"><h3 style="color: white;"> Item name </h3>
 <div style=" height: 30px; background-color:#ED5E13; padding-top: 1px; border-top: 1px dotted;border-bottom: 1px dotted;border-left: 1px dotted;border-color: #BFBFBF; text-align:center; padding-top:5px;font-size:small;"> Wooden spetula </div>
 <div style="height: 30px; background-color:#ED5E13; border-bottom: 1px dotted;border-left: 1px dotted;border-color: #BFBFBF; text-align:center;padding-top:5px;font-size:small;"> Pot </div>
 <div style="height: 30px; background-color:#ED5E13; border-bottom: 1px dotted;border-left: 1px dotted;border-color: #BFBFBF; text-align:center;padding-top:5px; font-size:small;"> Pressure cooker </div>
 <div style="height: 30px; background-color:#ED5E13; border-bottom: 1px dotted;border-left: 1px dotted;border-color: #BFBFBF; text-align:center;padding-top:5px; font-size:small;"> Stainless steel bowl </div>
 <div style="height: 30px; background-color:#ED5E13; border-bottom: 1px dotted;border-left: 1px dotted;border-color: #BFBFBF; text-align:center;padding-top:5px; font-size:small;"> Butter knife </div>
 <div style="height: 30px; background-color:#ED5E13; border-bottom: 1px dotted;border-left: 1px dotted;border-color: #BFBFBF; text-align:center;padding-top:5px; font-size:small;"> Measuring cup </div>
 <div style="height: 30px; background-color:#ED5E13; border-bottom: 1px dotted;border-left: 1px dotted;border-color: #BFBFBF; text-align:center;padding-top:5px; font-size:small;"> Long serving plate </div>
 <div style="height: 30px; background-color:#ED5E13; border-bottom: 1px dotted;border-left: 1px dotted;border-color: #BFBFBF; text-align:center;padding-top:5px; font-size:small;"> Pestel & Mortar </div>
 <div style="height: 30px; background-color:#ED5E13; border-bottom: 1px dotted;border-left: 1px dotted;border-color: #BFBFBF; text-align:center;padding-top:5px; font-size:small;"> Knife </div>
 <div style="height: 30px; background-color:#ED5E13; border-bottom: 1px dotted;border-left: 1px dotted;border-color: #BFBFBF; text-align:center;padding-top:5px; font-size:small;"> Spoon </div>
 <div style="height: 30px; background-color:#ED5E13; border-bottom: 1px dotted;border-left: 1px dotted;border-color: #BFBFBF; text-align:center;padding-top:5px; font-size:small;"> Small bowl </div>
 <div style="height: 30px; background-color:#ED5E13; border-bottom: 1px dotted;border-left: 1px dotted;border-color: #BFBFBF; text-align:center;padding-top:5px; font-size:small;"> Strainer </div>
 <div style="height: 30px; background-color:#ED5E13; border-bottom: 1px dotted;border-left: 1px dotted;border-color: #BFBFBF; text-align:center;padding-top:5px; font-size:small;clear:both;"> Muslin cloth </div>
 </div>
    <div class="toolequip" style="width: 70%; height: 130px; background-color:#ED5E13; float:right; text-align:center; border-bottom: 1px dotted;border-left: 1px dotted; dotted;border-right: 1px dotted; border-color: #BFBFBF;  padding-top:15px;"><h3 style="color: white;"> See options, price & availability </h3>
 <div style="background-color:#ED5E13; border-top: 1px dotted;border-bottom: 1px dotted;border-left: 1px dotted;border-color: #BFBFBF; text-align:center; ">
     <div id="vendors">
      <div id="left" class="col" style="box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;height: 30px;background-color:white; color: black;border-right: 1px dotted; border-bottom: 1px dotted;border-color: #BFBFBF; padding-top:5px;cursor:pointer;"><i class="fab fa-amazon"></i><a href="#"style="text-decoration:none"><b>Amazon</b></a></div>
      <div id="center" class="col" style="box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;height: 30px;background-color:red; color: white;border-right: 1px dotted;border-bottom: 1px dotted;border-color: #BFBFBF;padding-top:5px;cursor:pointer;"><i class="fas fa-bullseye"></i><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;color: white;"> <b>Target</b></a></div>
      <div id="right" class="col" style="box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;height: 30px;background-color:#041E42; color: white;border-bottom: 1px dotted;border-color: #BFBFBF;padding-top:5px;cursor:pointer;"><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;color: white;"><b>Walmart</b></a></div>
     </div>
 
 
 </div>
 <div style="background-color:#ED5E13; border-bottom: 1px dotted;border-left: 1px dotted;border-color: #BFBFBF; text-align:center;"> 
   <div id="vendors">
      <div id="left" class="col" style=" box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;height: 30px;background-color:white; color: black;border-right: 1px dotted; border-bottom: 1px dotted;border-color: #BFBFBF;cursor:pointer;padding-top:5px;"><i class="fab fa-amazon"></i><a href="#"style="text-decoration:none;color: black;"><b>Amazon</b></a></div>
      <div id="center" class="col" style="box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;height: 30px;background-color:red; color: white; border-bottom: 1px dotted;border-right: 1px dotted;border-color: #BFBFBF;cursor:pointer;padding-top:5px;"><i class="fas fa-bullseye"></i><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;color: white;"> <b>Target</b></a></div>
      <div id="right" class="col" style="box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;height: 30px;background-color:#041E42; color: white; border-bottom: 1px dotted;border-color: #BFBFBF;cursor:pointer;padding-top:5px;"><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;color: white;"><b>Walmart</b></a></div>
     </div></div>
 <div style="background-color:#ED5E13; border-bottom: 1px dotted;border-left: 1px dotted;border-color: #BFBFBF; text-align:center;"> 
   <div id="vendors">
      <div id="left" class="col" style=" box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;height: 30px;background-color:white; color: black;border-right: 1px dotted; border-bottom: 1px dotted; border-color: #BFBFBF;cursor:pointer;padding-top:5px;"><i class="fab fa-amazon"></i><a href="#"style="text-decoration:none;color: black;"><b>Amazon</b></a></div>
      <div id="center" class="col" style="box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;height: 30px;background-color:red; color: white;white;border-right: 1px dotted;  border-bottom: 1px dotted;border-color: #BFBFBF;cursor:pointer;padding-top:5px;"><i class="fas fa-bullseye"></i><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;color: white;"> <b>Target</b></a></div>
      <div id="right" class="col" style="box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;height: 30px;background-color:#041E42; color: white;border-bottom: 1px dotted;border-color: #BFBFBF;cursor:pointer;padding-top:5px;"><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;color: white;"><b>Walmart</b></a></div>
     </div></div>
     <div style="background-color:#ED5E13; border-bottom: 1px dotted;border-left: 1px dotted;border-color: #BFBFBF; text-align:center;"> 
   <div id="vendors">
      <div id="left" class="col" style=" box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;height: 30px;background-color:white; color: black;border-right: 1px dotted; border-bottom: 1px dotted; border-color: #BFBFBF;cursor:pointer;padding-top:5px;"><i class="fab fa-amazon"></i><a href="#"style="text-decoration:none;color: black;"><b>Amazon</b></a></div>
      <div id="center" class="col" style="box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;height: 30px;background-color:red; color: white;white;border-right: 1px dotted;  border-bottom: 1px dotted;border-color: #BFBFBF;cursor:pointer;padding-top:5px;"><i class="fas fa-bullseye"></i><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;color: white;"> <b>Target</b></a></div>
      <div id="right" class="col" style="box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;height: 30px;background-color:#041E42; color: white;border-bottom: 1px dotted;border-color: #BFBFBF;cursor:pointer;padding-top:5px;"><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;color: white;"><b>Walmart</b></a></div>
     </div></div>
     <div style="background-color:#ED5E13; border-bottom: 1px dotted;border-left: 1px dotted;border-color: #BFBFBF; text-align:center;"> 
   <div id="vendors">
      <div id="left" class="col" style=" box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;height: 30px;background-color:white; color: black;border-right: 1px dotted; border-bottom: 1px dotted; border-color: #BFBFBF;cursor:pointer;padding-top:5px;"><i class="fab fa-amazon"></i><a href="#"style="text-decoration:none;color: black;"><b>Amazon</b></a></div>
      <div id="center" class="col" style="box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;height: 30px;background-color:red; color: white;white;border-right: 1px dotted;  border-bottom: 1px dotted;border-color: #BFBFBF;cursor:pointer;padding-top:5px;"><i class="fas fa-bullseye"></i><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;color: white;"> <b>Target</b></a></div>
      <div id="right" class="col" style="box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;height: 30px;background-color:#041E42; color: white;border-bottom: 1px dotted;border-color: #BFBFBF;cursor:pointer;padding-top:5px;"><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;color: white;"><b>Walmart</b></a></div>
     </div></div>
     <div style="background-color:#ED5E13; border-bottom: 1px dotted;border-left: 1px dotted;border-color: #BFBFBF; text-align:center;"> 
   <div id="vendors">
      <div id="left" class="col" style=" box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;height: 30px;background-color:white; color: black;border-right: 1px dotted; border-bottom: 1px dotted; border-color: #BFBFBF;cursor:pointer;padding-top:5px;"><i class="fab fa-amazon"></i><a href="#"style="text-decoration:none;color: black;"><b>Amazon</b></a></div>
      <div id="center" class="col" style="box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;height: 30px;background-color:red; color: white;white;border-right: 1px dotted;  border-bottom: 1px dotted;border-color: #BFBFBF;cursor:pointer;padding-top:5px;"><i class="fas fa-bullseye"></i><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;color: white;"> <b>Target</b></a></div>
      <div id="right" class="col" style="box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;height: 30px;background-color:#041E42; color: white;border-bottom: 1px dotted;border-color: #BFBFBF;cursor:pointer;padding-top:5px;"><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;color: white;"><b>Walmart</b></a></div>
     </div></div>
     <div style="background-color:#ED5E13; border-bottom: 1px dotted;border-left: 1px dotted;border-color: #BFBFBF; text-align:center;"> 
   <div id="vendors">
      <div id="left" class="col" style=" box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;height: 30px;background-color:white; color: black;border-right: 1px dotted; border-bottom: 1px dotted; border-color: #BFBFBF;cursor:pointer;padding-top:5px;"><i class="fab fa-amazon"></i><a href="#"style="text-decoration:none;color: black;"><b>Amazon</b></a></div>
      <div id="center" class="col" style="box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;height: 30px;background-color:red; color: white;white;border-right: 1px dotted;  border-bottom: 1px dotted;border-color: #BFBFBF;cursor:pointer;padding-top:5px;"><i class="fas fa-bullseye"></i><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;color: white;"> <b>Target</b></a></div>
      <div id="right" class="col" style="box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;height: 30px;background-color:#041E42; color: white;border-bottom: 1px dotted;border-color: #BFBFBF;cursor:pointer;padding-top:5px;"><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;color: white;"><b>Walmart</b></a></div>
     </div></div>
     <div style="background-color:#ED5E13; border-bottom: 1px dotted;border-left: 1px dotted;border-color: #BFBFBF; text-align:center;"> 
   <div id="vendors">
      <div id="left" class="col" style=" box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;height: 30px;background-color:white; color: black;border-right: 1px dotted; border-bottom: 1px dotted; border-color: #BFBFBF;cursor:pointer;padding-top:5px;"><i class="fab fa-amazon"></i><a href="#"style="text-decoration:none;color: black;"><b>Amazon</b></a></div>
      <div id="center" class="col" style="box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;height: 30px;background-color:red; color: white;white;border-right: 1px dotted;  border-bottom: 1px dotted;border-color: #BFBFBF;cursor:pointer;padding-top:5px;"><i class="fas fa-bullseye"></i><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;color: white;"> <b>Target</b></a></div>
      <div id="right" class="col" style="box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;height: 30px;background-color:#041E42; color: white;border-bottom: 1px dotted;border-color: #BFBFBF;cursor:pointer;padding-top:5px;"><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;color: white;"><b>Walmart</b></a></div>
     </div></div>
     <div style="background-color:#ED5E13; border-bottom: 1px dotted;border-left: 1px dotted;border-color: #BFBFBF; text-align:center;"> 
   <div id="vendors">
      <div id="left" class="col" style=" box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;height: 30px;background-color:white; color: black;border-right: 1px dotted; border-bottom: 1px dotted; border-color: #BFBFBF;cursor:pointer;padding-top:5px;"><i class="fab fa-amazon"></i><a href="#"style="text-decoration:none;color: black;"><b>Amazon</b></a></div>
      <div id="center" class="col" style="box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;height: 30px;background-color:red; color: white;white;border-right: 1px dotted;  border-bottom: 1px dotted;border-color: #BFBFBF;cursor:pointer;padding-top:5px;"><i class="fas fa-bullseye"></i><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;color: white;"> <b>Target</b></a></div>
      <div id="right" class="col" style="box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;height: 30px;background-color:#041E42; color: white;border-bottom: 1px dotted;border-color: #BFBFBF;cursor:pointer;padding-top:5px;"><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;color: white;"><b>Walmart</b></a></div>
     </div></div>
     <div style="background-color:#ED5E13; border-bottom: 1px dotted;border-left: 1px dotted;border-color: #BFBFBF; text-align:center;"> 
   <div id="vendors">
      <div id="left" class="col" style=" box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;height: 30px;background-color:white; color: black;border-right: 1px dotted; border-bottom: 1px dotted; border-color: #BFBFBF;cursor:pointer;padding-top:5px;"><i class="fab fa-amazon"></i><a href="#"style="text-decoration:none;color: black;"><b>Amazon</b></a></div>
      <div id="center" class="col" style="box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;height: 30px;background-color:red; color: white;white;border-right: 1px dotted;  border-bottom: 1px dotted;border-color: #BFBFBF;cursor:pointer;padding-top:5px;"><i class="fas fa-bullseye"></i><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;color: white;"> <b>Target</b></a></div>
      <div id="right" class="col" style="box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;height: 30px;background-color:#041E42; color: white;border-bottom: 1px dotted;border-color: #BFBFBF;cursor:pointer;padding-top:5px;"><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;color: white;"><b>Walmart</b></a></div>
     </div></div>
     <div style="background-color:#ED5E13; border-bottom: 1px dotted;border-left: 1px dotted;border-color: #BFBFBF; text-align:center;"> 
   <div id="vendors">
      <div id="left" class="col" style=" box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;height: 30px;background-color:white; color: black;border-right: 1px dotted; border-bottom: 1px dotted; border-color: #BFBFBF;cursor:pointer;padding-top:5px;"><i class="fab fa-amazon"></i><a href="#"style="text-decoration:none;color: black;"><b>Amazon</b></a></div>
      <div id="center" class="col" style="box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;height: 30px;background-color:red; color: white;white;border-right: 1px dotted;  border-bottom: 1px dotted;border-color: #BFBFBF;cursor:pointer;padding-top:5px;"><i class="fas fa-bullseye"></i><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;color: white;"> <b>Target</b></a></div>
      <div id="right" class="col" style="box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;height: 30px;background-color:#041E42; color: white;border-bottom: 1px dotted;border-color: #BFBFBF;cursor:pointer;padding-top:5px;"><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;color: white;"><b>Walmart</b></a></div>
     </div></div>
     <div style="background-color:#ED5E13; border-bottom: 1px dotted;border-left: 1px dotted;border-color: #BFBFBF; text-align:center;"> 
   <div id="vendors">
      <div id="left" class="col" style=" box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;height: 30px;background-color:white; color: black;border-right: 1px dotted; border-bottom: 1px dotted; border-color: #BFBFBF;cursor:pointer;padding-top:5px;"><i class="fab fa-amazon"></i><a href="#"style="text-decoration:none;color: black;"><b>Amazon</b></a></div>
      <div id="center" class="col" style="box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;height: 30px;background-color:red; color: white;white;border-right: 1px dotted;  border-bottom: 1px dotted;border-color: #BFBFBF;cursor:pointer;padding-top:5px;"><i class="fas fa-bullseye"></i><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;color: white;"> <b>Target</b></a></div>
      <div id="right" class="col" style="box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;height: 30px;background-color:#041E42; color: white;border-bottom: 1px dotted;border-color: #BFBFBF;cursor:pointer;padding-top:5px;"><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;color: white;"><b>Walmart</b></a></div>
     </div></div>
     <div style="background-color:#ED5E13; border-bottom: 1px dotted;border-left: 1px dotted;border-color: #BFBFBF; text-align:center;"> 
   <div id="vendors">
      <div id="left" class="col" style=" box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;height: 30px;background-color:white; color: black;border-right: 1px dotted; border-bottom: 1px dotted; border-color: #BFBFBF;cursor:pointer;padding-top:5px;"><i class="fab fa-amazon"></i><a href="#"style="text-decoration:none;color: black;"><b>Amazon</b></a></div>
      <div id="center" class="col" style="box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;height: 30px;background-color:red; color: white;white;border-right: 1px dotted;  border-bottom: 1px dotted;border-color: #BFBFBF;cursor:pointer;padding-top:5px;"><i class="fas fa-bullseye"></i><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;color: white;"> <b>Target</b></a></div>
      <div id="right" class="col" style="box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;height: 30px;background-color:#041E42; color: white;border-bottom: 1px dotted;border-color: #BFBFBF;cursor:pointer;padding-top:5px;"><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;color: white;"><b>Walmart</b></a></div>
     </div></div>
 </div>
 
  <h2 style="text-align:left">Cham Cham Recipe Description</h2>
  </div> <!--end of maincolumn mainmiddle-->
  <div class="maincolumn mainright" style="background-color:#ccc;">
    <h2>Column 3</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that's because you have written it inside the div

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. I had to increase the height of the parent div to accommodate all the child divs.